# Import Multiple space delimited files into one Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote this and it works for the most part...for the first file I find. on the second file, I get the following error:

"The information cannot be pasted because the Copy area and the paste area are not the same size and shape. Try one of the following:

- Click a single cell, and then paste.
- Select a rectangle that's the
  same size and shape, and then paste."

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

It is suppose to traverse a directory and grab all the .txt files that are there and import them into either Sheet1 or Sheet2. I can get the first one to import fine, but the next file throws that error instead of appending to the same spreadsheet.

```
Sub PopulateSheets()

    Dim file As String, path As String, fullpath As String, StaticPath As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet
    Dim Sheet As String
    Dim RowCount As Long
    On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    RowCount = 1
    count = 1
    StaticPath = Sheet3.Cells(2, 7)
    While (count <= 2)

        If count = 1 Then
            path = StaticPath & "\com\*.txt"
        Else
            path = StaticPath & "\res\*.txt"
        End If
        file = Dir(path)
        Sheet = "Sheet" & count
        While (file <> "")
            fullpath = Left(path, InStr(1, path, "*.txt") - 1) & file
            Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
            Set wsI = wbI.Sheets(Sheet) '<~~ Sheet where I want to import
            Set wbO = Workbooks.Open(fullpath)
            RowCount = wsI.Range("A:A").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
            wbO.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=wsI.Range("A" & RowCount)
            wbO.Close SaveChanges:=False
            file = Dir 'Grab Next File
        Wend
        count = count + 1
    Wend
Exit Sub

Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

It blows up at `wbO.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=wsI.Range("A" & RowCount)` after it has pasted the information from the first file, closed it, then tries to paste the second file.

Any help would be appreciated at this point.

*Side note*
I have noticed that if I swap`wbO.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=wsI.Range("A" & RowCount)` with  `wbO.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wsI.Cells` , it will paste all of the files into the sheet...but it overwrites the file before it. I need it to append and not sure how to make that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question by swapping the logic inside the While (File <> "") loop to read:

```
       fullpath = Left(path, InStr(1, path, "*.txt") - 1) & file
        Set wbO = Workbooks.Open(fullpath)
        RowCount = wsI.UsedRange.Rows.count
        SourceRowCount = wbO.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
        If RowCount <> 1 Then
            RowCount = RowCount + 2
            SourceRowCount = RowCount + SourceRowCount
        End If
        wbO.Sheets(1).Range("$A$1:$n$" & SourceRowCount).Copy Destination:=wsI.Range("A" & RowCount & ":$n$" & SourceRowCount)
        wbO.Close SaveChanges:=False
        file = Dir 'Grab Next File`
```

I have the row count adding two each time so that I have a blank space between the imports. Everything works now as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "reset" the value of `path`. If your path is "C:\MyFolder" (for example), the first time through the loop, your `path` is

"C:\MyFolder\com\*.txt"

When you go through the loop again, the path becomes...

"C:\MyFolder\com\*.txt\res\*.txt"

...which creates an invalid path. Update the code as per below.

```
count = count + 1
' ADD THE LINE BELOW TO YOUR CODE
path = Sheet3.Cells(2, 7)
```

Comment: the path part works like a champ actually. It is grabbing all of the files that are in the directory as needed. The problem is when the vba code goes to put it in the sheet. The value for the path is something like "C:\Comres". Depending on whether it is the first pass or second pass i go to C:\comres\com or \res. So that part is not the issue, it works.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I put a StaticPath variable to hold the path which fixes that little guy, but that still does not help the issue since it is how the data is being copied into the spreadsheet and not how it is accessing it.